# TableLayout resizes when TableRow is full

Tags: android, xml, resize, android-tablelayout, android-layout-weight

I have a problem with always resizing `TableLayout`. Every time I fill one `TableRow` with `ImageView`, the table is formatting and I just want it fixed.

As in the first picture, the row is filled with 5/6 `ImageView`s inside each cell. After I put one circle in the last(6th cell of the row), it re-formats.

[5_circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHndk.png)
[6_circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoLa5.png)

I am assuming that I have used `android:stretch_columns`and `android:layout_weight` wrong, but I can't really find what source of the problem is.

Here is my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context="com.example.orderchaos.MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_below="@+id/red_circle"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/a0"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:tag="0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/a1"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:tag="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/a2"
                android:tag="2"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/a3"
                android:tag="3"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/a4"
                android:tag="4"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/a5"
                android:tag="5"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/b0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:tag="6"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:tag="7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:tag="8"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:tag="9"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:id="@+id/b4"
                android:tag="10"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/b5"
                android:tag="11"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/c0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:tag="12"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:id="@+id/c1"
                android:tag="13"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/c2"
                android:tag="14"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/c3"
                android:tag="15"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/c4"
                android:tag="16"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/c5"
                android:tag="17"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:tag="18"
                android:id="@+id/d0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/d1"
                android:tag="19"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/d2"
                android:tag="20"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/d3"
                android:tag="21"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/d4"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:tag="22"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/d5"
                android:tag="23"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/e0"
                android:tag="24"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/e1"
                android:tag="25"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/e2"
                android:tag="26"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/e3"
                android:tag="27"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/e4"
                android:tag="28"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/e5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:tag="29"
                android:clickable="true" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/f0"
                android:tag="30"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/f1"
                android:tag="31"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/f2"
                android:tag="32"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/f3"
                android:tag="33"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/f4"
                android:tag="34"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/inv_cell"
                android:onClick="ClickCell"
                android:id="@+id/f5"
                android:tag="35"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" >

            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/red_circle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_marginStart="105dp"
        android:background="@drawable/red_button"
        android:maxWidth="50dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/clear_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/blue_circle"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/red_circle"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/red_circle"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```